# EXM report is empty (data is not being captured) in scaled environment

Tags: azure, sitecore-api, exm, reporting

I am working with Sitecore 9.0 update 2 on Azure.

Server is scale out : 1CM and 3CD.

After email campaign is run, we can receive email but reporting is not working.
It doesn't have any data is as shown.

I checked in Campaigns table in database, data isn't stored.

[image]

```
In addition, I saw an error when I open email that is sent by EXM 
1724 11:57:37 ERROR Failed to get a registration result
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd
```

Any suggestion for this issues ?

More info:

Open and click rates show after i open email but report is not updated

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste the full error message

Comment: 2018-10-25T11:52:10  PID[4852] Error       7144 11:52:10 ERROR Failed to get a registration result
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.sitecore_modules.Web.EXM.RegisterEmailOpened.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)

Comment: I think you are having an issue with xConnect. I suspect that Collection Service and Reference Data are not working correctly. Or there is a connection string issue.

Comment: What happens when you open up Experience Analytics?

Comment: It showed report but it isn't updated after i migrate xdb from v8 (using mongo) to v9. I see the data is not auto collect and update to reporting. Any suggest to fix this ?

Comment: I'm concerned you have a problem with the processing of your analytic data given your comment. If this was a full upgrade, it's possible you have config files laying around that you probably don't want. I would compare your current configs with that of a vanilla 9.0.2 Cloud zip and see if there are configs laying around that shouldn't.  As an example, most ALL of the Sitecore configs have been removed from the `Include` folder and into the `Sitecore` folder.

Comment: What is value on the CM server in the web.config for `role:define`? If I had to guess, you have it currently set as "ContentManagement".  This might be your problem, as you state that you only have CM and CD's scaled out. If that's the case, you're missing your Processing and Reporting roles, which would explain why analytics isn't working.  You will want `role:define` to be set as *Standalone* since it appears that you do not have roles for Reporting and Processing (per question information). Update your question, if that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the campaign attached to this email is published and if it is available in all languages.

[image: Email Campaign]

Comment: It is published after i run campaign

Comment: It is so strength cause after the campaign is completed. Total sent still show none value although i received  emails

Comment: Unfortunatly, this fix doesn't work retro-active. You need to do this before sending out the campaign...

Comment: thanks @Bart Verdonck but i meam after i run a exm campaign, those campaigns is published automatically and i don't need publish anything

Comment: The campaign get's published when you activate the message. However, there is a bug that it only creates an en-version of the campaign. When visitors click or open the mail, sitecore tries to fetch that campaign in their language. Since the language doesn't exist, this fails. So workarround is to manually create the language versions of this campaign and deploy an publish them.

Comment: But the campaign item is created after delivery, how can we do this before sending the campaign ?

Comment: Actually the campaign item is created upon activation. For regular campaigns, you can first send them out in emulation mode. This will create the campaign but not actually send the emails.

Comment: i tried it, still not work. i worry that processing can't call event to update back data into database. Any suggestion for how to check this trigger is work or block by st ?

Answer (score 0):

After long time to investigate, I fixed it. In my case. Because i migrated big analytic data from mongo to xdb. Then a lot of query is processing. We need to scale up environment , rebuild xdb then wait all done.

Answer (score -1):

Solution, which worked for me in similar issue (empty "total sent" statistics in EXM on scaled environment), but in Sitecore 8.2 was to enable on CM server:

- `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Database.ScaledCM.config`
- `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Aggregation.config`

according to https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-the-interaction-registry-on-a-content-management-server.html

Comment: This is ONLY a solution for a Sitecore 8.2 implementation, and not valid for the question being asked since the asker has specified Sitecore 9.