# EXM Report | Data is not getting aggregated

Tags: exm, reporting, aggregation

Environment details: Sitecore 9.0.2 Scaled in PAAS model

What is happening:
We have deployed a set of e-mail campaigns, both regular and automated in the environment.
The mails are getting triggered and delivered properly.

The problem is with the reporting.

On the EXM dashboard, the details such as recipient activity, technology are not getting rendered.
[image]

On the dashboard of the individual campaigns also, this data is not coming.
[image]

Surprisingly, for the campaign, under the tab 'Recipient Activity', in the lower -half (highlighted in the image) we can see the recipient activity.
[image]

I do get data under 'Experience Profile'.

I have seen this link [EXM report is empty (data is not being captured) in scaled environment](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14601/exm-report-is-empty-data-is-not-being-captured-in-scaled-environment) but couldn't move ahead.

In my CM instance, there are entries for

```
ERROR Failed to get a registration result
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.sitecore_modules.Web.EXM.RegisterEmailOpened.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
```

**Edit**:

On the processing instance, I do have the following logs. I am not sure if these are related.

```
    ERROR Exception when executing agent pathAnalyzer/mapRebuildStatusCheckerAgent
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.MapRebuildStatusCheckerAgent.<GetDefinitionsWithUpdatedStatus>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.MapRebuildStatusCheckerAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.MapRebuildStatusCheckerAgent.<ResolveMapRebuildStatus>d__9.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Data.EntityDoesNotExistException
Message: Routine caused exception: Processing_GetTaskById.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.Sql
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.SqlTaskDataProvider.<GetProcessingTaskUsingRoutineAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.SqlTaskDataProvider.<GetAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Internals.TaskHub.<GetTaskAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TaskManager.<GetTaskAsync>d__8.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: A processing task with the specified unique identifier does not exist.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__180_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Sql.Common.Extensions.DbCommandExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Sql.Common.Extensions.DbCommandExtensions.<ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Sql.Common.Extensions.SqlCommandExtensions.<ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Sql.Common.Extensions.SqlCommandExtensions.<ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.SqlTaskDataProvider.<GetProcessingTaskUsingRoutineAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
```

**Edit 2**:

Under 'Experience Profile' I am able to see data and filter them out on the basis of the e-mail campaign.

At the same time, we are not getting the data on the 'Experience Analytics' dashboard.

Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What about *Experience Analytics*? Do you see data in there? Basically, *Experience Profile* reads data from the index rather than the database while *ExM*, *Path Analyzer* and *Experience Analytics* read data from the reporting database. In order to aggregate the data in reporting database, the processing role would run certain tasks. Seems like something is wrong with your processing role and it’s not able to aggregate the data. The errors you shared, represent the issue with *Path Analyzer* aggregations. *Path Analyzer* and *Experience Analytics* have their own tasks for aggregation but ExM is being aggregated by Experience Analytics.
Few things that can help

1. Redeploy the *Path Analyzer* maps to resolve the above errors
2. Redeploy marketing definitions
3. Redeploy experience Analytics Segments

Once you are done with this, trigger another email and see if the campaigns' data is coming up
I worked with these components, happy to share more details.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Under the experience profile, I do see data. Even I filtered out on the basis of the e-mail campaign also we are able to see the last 10 days data.

Comment: Experience profile reads from the index which is built directly from xdb. Looking at the error for Path Analyzer, it’s clear that you have issues with aggregation running on processing role. It could be one of the three things I mentioned above or Connection to reporting database is not working from Processing role